# SQL optimization issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, join

I have two tables. One table contains information about Assets, another Table about their relation. How could I optimize current query and getting similar results.

```
SELECT a1.ID FROM Asset a1
WHERE a1.AssetId =
(SELECT r.DestinationAssetId
FROM Relation r
INNER JOIN Asset a2 ON a2.AssetId = r.SourceAssetId
WHERE a2.ID = '1112174' and r.RelationshipType = 'Video File')
```

Results: 13412331 (ID of Asset which is related to a2.ID = '1125574')

Personally I don't like this stupid sub query, is it any way I can avoid it and optimize this query.

Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using?  Why can't you join relation to asset?

Comment: MSQL, I can join Relation to Asset, and I am doing that in sub query. But how to get the same results in one query.

Comment: Optimization would also involve making sure that the JOINed columns have matching data types and that suitable indexes are in place.  You should have a look at the _query plan_ that SQL Server generates to see where it is spending its time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lose the subquery:

```
SELECT dest.ID 
FROM 
Asset src
JOIN Relation r ON src.AssetId = r.SourceAssetId
JOIN Asset dest ON dest.AssetID = r.DestinationAssetID
WHERE src.ID = '1112174' and r.RelationshipType = 'Video File'
```

Its not much of an optimization performance wise, but it is a little neater.

Comment: @af: Taa - did that on half of the times I typed it! thought I'd spotted them all.

Comment: @DarkTygur, I agree with Jon..  The First FROM table being the basis on the specific ID he is looking for, then join out to the others for the other qualifying information elements.

Comment: I like better table aliases in this answer than the others. Do yourself a favor and use meaningful alias like Jon has.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, it looks like this would do the same thing:

```
SELECT a1.ID
FROM Relation r
INNER JOIN Asset a2 ON a2.AssetId = r.SourceAssetId
INNER JOIN Asset a1 ON a1.AssetId = r.DestinationAssetId
WHERE a2.ID = '1112174' and r.RelationshipType = 'Video File'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a1.ID
FROM Asset a1
INNER JOIN Relation r ON a1.AssetId = r.DestinationAssetId
INNER JOIN Asset a2 ON a2.AssetId = r.SourceAssetId
WHERE a2.ID = '1112174' and r.RelationshipType = 'Video File'
```